# How to make javascript check image exist callback function synchronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have this javascript function which checks if a certain image path exists.
currently, the function is not finishing before the rest of the code is being executed. if anyone can recommend a way to make the program wait till this function is finished before continuing execution that would be amazing. Thanks!

```
var flag = false;

function checkImageExists(imageUrl, callBack) {
    var imageData = new Image();
    imageData.onload = function () {
        callBack(true);
    };
    imageData.onerror = function () {
        callBack(false);
    };
    imageData.src = imageUrl;
}

checkImageExists(card.logoSrc, function (existsImage) {
    if (existsImage === true) {
        flag = true;
        console.log(card.logoSrc + ' ' + flag);
    } else {
        flag = false;
        console.log(card.logoSrc + ' ' + flag);
    }
});
console.log('flag ' + flag);
```

The console log of this program displays the image url and the correct flag value but this is only displayed after the 'flag' + flag log is executed as false at all times due to the function not finishing its execution. Any advice or recommendations would be greatly appreciated thanks again!

Comment: It's working as expected because your `console.log('flag ' + flag)` out of the function hence it gives the values first, the  console.log inside checkImageExists returning later because it checking URL exists or not

Comment: You can't. You'll need to write your program in a way that doesn't rely on a value being returned immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `async/await` to make it act as if it was synchronous.

```
function checkImageExists(imageUrl) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let imageData = new Image();

    imageData.onload = function () {
        resolve(true);
    };
    imageData.onerror = function () {
        reject(false);
    };

    // not really sure why you have this here, but ok
    imageData.src = imageUrl;
  });
}

async function init() {
  try {
    const isImageLoaded = await checkImageExists(card.logoSrc);
    console.log(isImageLoaded);
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

init();
```

Note that this is untested code, it's just to provide an idea of a solution.

Example: https://repl.it/repls/KhakiTreasuredTasks

Comment: is there any way to do this with old javascript promises without using the arrow function an async await? or better yet what would the function call look like to catch the promise? thanks @Baruch

Comment: @ChrisKelly Why would you want to do it the old way? These are native javascript functionailties. Also, updated the answer to catch the errors.

Comment: i'm working with legacy code at my work place and was unable to use async await! thanks for your help